# Motivation for Schur multipliers

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, group-cohomology

What are Schur multipliers good for?

I should probably clarify what I want. Here is an instructive story of how I came to appreciate complex representations and characters of groups. Basically, I always felt that this was something that I should learn, a "trendy" "cool" topic. But that was not *real* interest. Real interest came when I heard about Burnside's [pq-theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_theorem). This is a cool fact that doesn't explicitly mention representations, but you need to use representations to prove it. This is enough motivation to really get me interested.

Is there a similar thing for Schur multipliers (or group (co)homology in general)? Is there a classic problem that you cannot solve without using group homology, but not about homology per se? Any suggestions are welcome.

Also, if you know of a book that can answer my question, please tell me.

Comment: The Schur multiplier wikipedia article addresses a few motivations. Projective representations help to understand extending representations from normal subgroups. The number of relations versus number of generators is affected by the rank of the Schur multiplier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not about groups, but Lie algebras. Please keep in mind that by trade I am a group theorist, which happened to venture in the field of graded (over the positive integers) Lie algebras, discovering that they do not look too different from (residually) nilpotent groups.

Anyway, I was studying certain twisted loop algebras, trying too prove they were finitely presented. Turned out they weren't. And the reason was that the finite-dimensional Lie algebra I was starting from had a non-trivial Schur multiplier. This Schur multiplier kept popping up at each loop iteration, making a finite presentation impossible.

So my moral from this little story is that you study Schur multipliers because you cannot avoid them - they appear while you do other things, so you'd better face them.

To address more directly your question, though, there are results such as the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem, or the result of Gaschütz that a non-abelian, finite $p$-group has an outer automorphism, that benefit from the use of cohomology.

Comment: It is a nice answer.

Comment: @BorisNovikov, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can find many applications of cohomology in the book

K.Brown, Cohomology of groups,

in particular, in exercises (there is Russian translation).

As to Schur multiplier, there is a very comprehensive book

Karpilovsky, Gregory: The Schur Multiplier, Oxford University Press, 1987

(it is in Internet).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give them a read.

Comment: Now that I've had time to read enough of it, Brown's book turned out to be exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: @ Dan Shved: Желаю успехов!